# Why is another term for StandardScaler is Z-Score Normalization if it uses Standardization?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization, scaling, standardization

I found this online:
"StandardScaler or Z-Score Normalization is one of the feature scaling techniques, here the transformation of features is done by subtracting from the mean and dividing by standard deviation. This is often called Z-score normalization. The resulting data will have the mean as 0 and the standard deviation as 1."

To sum it up: why is it called Z-Score Normalization if it uses a Standardization technique?

What I'm thinking is that if it is called Z-Score Normalization shouldn't it use a Normalization technique rather than a Standardization one?

Comment: Z-Score normalization **is** standard normalization. You can view Z-score and Standard score as synonym for each other.

Comment: @VioletAster The MinMaxScaler uses the minimum and maximum value of features for scaling, not StandardScaler

Comment: What is your definition of a "normalization technique", and how does it differ from your definition of a "standardization technique"?

Answer (score 1):

According to [sklearn StandardScaler documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html):

`StandardScaler` standardize features by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance.

The standard score of a sample `x` is calculated as:

`z = (x - u) / s` (The formula for calculating a z-score)

So, both of `StandardScaler` (standard normalization) and `Z-Score Normalization` use the same formula and they are equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your response Hamid Rasti. So in this case, the naming doesn't have any relevance? Even though is it called Z-Score Normalization, it bears no connection to Normalization?

Comment: Yes, the naming doesn't have any relevance. both of them are a type of normalization. and they are the same. As of @sagi commented, You can view Z-score and Standard score as synonym for each other.